# Format of data array in D3 bar chart, array of values into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multidimensional-array, charts

I have a Simple interactive bar chart. Most like Mike Bostock's http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304 but with a tooltip on the bar.

The 2d array elements I have has the format "word" string, frequency number as in...

**good,5
hello,4
bye,2
aloha,1
...**

I tried concatenating "letter:" and "frequency:" to the 2d array elements to follow this code. but it is not working anyway. The string concatenate is probably casting the frequency number into a string type.  So at all sure how to work with this.

Is there a way to concatenate a string to a number in an array elements to preserve the type, especially of the number?

Or there a way to load data better for my current array into an array of objects??

I will be working with files as well in the future. But for now the arrays Thanks for suggestions...

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - bar chart demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>

  <style type='text/css'>
    body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
  </style>




<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){

}//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.frequency + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

// The new data variable.
var data = [
  {letter: "A", frequency: .08167},
  {letter: "B", frequency: .01492},
  {letter: "C", frequency: .02780},
  {letter: "D", frequency: .04253},
  {letter: "E", frequency: .12702},
  {letter: "F", frequency: .02288},
  {letter: "G", frequency: .02022},
  {letter: "H", frequency: .06094},
  {letter: "I", frequency: .06973},
  {letter: "J", frequency: .00153},
  {letter: "K", frequency: .00747},
  {letter: "L", frequency: .04025},
  {letter: "M", frequency: .02517},
  {letter: "N", frequency: .06749},
  {letter: "O", frequency: .07507},
  {letter: "P", frequency: .01929},
  {letter: "Q", frequency: .00098},
  {letter: "R", frequency: .05987},
  {letter: "S", frequency: .06333},
  {letter: "T", frequency: .09056},
  {letter: "U", frequency: .02758},
  {letter: "V", frequency: .01037},
  {letter: "W", frequency: .02465},
  {letter: "X", frequency: .00150},
  {letter: "Y", frequency: .01971},
  {letter: "Z", frequency: .00074}
];

// The following code was contained in the callback function.
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.frequency); })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

function type(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}

</script>

</body>

</html>

</pre>
```

This section has to be changed for my array format:

```
// The new data variable.
var data = [
  {letter: "A", frequency: .08167},
  {letter: "B", frequency: .01492},
  {letter: "C", frequency: .02780},
  {letter: "D", frequency: .04253},
  {letter: "E", frequency: .12702},
  {letter: "F", frequency: .02288},
  {letter: "G", frequency: .02022},
  {letter: "H", frequency: .06094},
  {letter: "I", frequency: .06973},
  {letter: "J", frequency: .00153},
  {letter: "K", frequency: .00747},
  {letter: "L", frequency: .04025},
  {letter: "M", frequency: .02517},
  {letter: "N", frequency: .06749},
  {letter: "O", frequency: .07507},
  {letter: "P", frequency: .01929},
  {letter: "Q", frequency: .00098},
  {letter: "R", frequency: .05987},
  {letter: "S", frequency: .06333},
  {letter: "T", frequency: .09056},
  {letter: "U", frequency: .02758},
  {letter: "V", frequency: .01037},
  {letter: "W", frequency: .02465},
  {letter: "X", frequency: .00150},
  {letter: "Y", frequency: .01971},
  {letter: "Z", frequency: .00074}
];

// The following code was contained in the callback function.
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```